# libnfc fails to connect to PN532 via I2C with timeout error

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, raspberry-pi-zero, lib-nfc, pn532

I want to read NFC tags using a PN532 NFC reader, which is connected via I2C to a Raspberry Pi Zero. The Pi has I2C enabled via `raspi-config`.

When attempting to access the device using `nfc-list` or `nfc-pull` I get a timeout error:

```bash
$ nfc-list
debug   libnfc.general  log_level is set to 3
debug   libnfc.general  allow_autoscan is set to true
debug   libnfc.general  allow_intrusive_scan is set to false
debug   libnfc.general  1 device(s) defined by user
debug   libnfc.general    #0 name: "PN532 over I2C", connstring: "pn532_i2c:/dev/i2c-1"
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.8.0
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using acr122_usb driver
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using pn53x_usb driver
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x       Diagnose
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x       Timeout value: 500
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x       SAMConfiguration
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x       Timeout value: 1000
debug   libnfc.bus.i2c  TX: 00 00 ff 03 fd d4 14 01 17 00
debug   libnfc.bus.i2c  wrote 10 bytes successfully.
debug   libnfc.driver.pn532_i2c timeout reached with no READY frame.
pn53x_check_communication: Timeout
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x       InRelease
debug   libnfc.bus.i2c  TX: 00 00 ff 03 fd d4 52 00 da 00
debug   libnfc.bus.i2c  wrote 10 bytes successfully.
debug   libnfc.driver.pn532_i2c timeout reached with no READY frame.
debug   libnfc.general  Unable to open "pn532_i2c:/dev/i2c-1".
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: pn532_i2c:/dev/i2c-1
```

It may be related that i2cdetect reports that there exists a device at every address once the PN532 is connected to the Pi:

```bash
$ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f
10: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f
20: 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f
30: 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f
40: 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f
50: 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e 5f
60: 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f
70: 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
```

If the PN532 is disconnected from the Pi, i2cdetect only finds one device:

```
$ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 67 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

There are only two i2c interfaces in /dev and i2c-2 does not have any connected devices.

```bash
$ ls -la /dev/ | grep i2c
crw-rw----   1 root i2c      89,   1 Jun 23 15:39 i2c-1
crw-rw----   1 root i2c      89,   2 Jun 23 15:35 i2c-2
```

How do I fix the timeout error?

Comment: Have you installed / adjusted pull-up resistors?

Comment: @0andriy Are you refering to the resitors on the PN532? Those have been set to I2C

Comment: Nope, the resistors for SCL and SDA signals.